# Suffix Tree in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree

I was wondering why the following implementation of a Suffix Tree is 2000 times slower than using a similar data structure in C++ (I tested it using python3, pypy3 and pypy2). I know the bottleneck is the `traverse` method, do you spot chance of optimisation in the following code? Thanks!

```
from sys import stdin, stdout, stderr, setrecursionlimit
setrecursionlimit(100000)

def read():
    return stdin.readline().rstrip()

def readint():
    return int(read())

def make_node(_pos, _len):
    global s, n, sz, to, link, fpos, slen, pos, node
    fpos[sz] = _pos
    slen[sz] = _len
    sz += 1
    return sz-1

def go_edge():
    global s, n, sz, to, link, fpos, slen, pos, node
    while (pos > slen[to[node].get(s[n - pos], 0)]):
        node = to[node].get(s[n - pos], 0)
        pos -= slen[node]

def add_letter(c):
    global s, n, sz, to, link, fpos, slen, pos, node
    s[n] = c
    n += 1
    pos += 1
    last = 0
    while(pos > 0):
        go_edge()
        edge = s[n - pos]
        v = to[node].get(edge, 0)
        t = s[fpos[v] + pos - 1]
        if (v == 0):
            to[node][edge] = make_node(n - pos, inf)
            link[last] = node
            last = 0
        elif (t == c):
            link[last] = node
            return
        else:
            u = make_node(fpos[v], pos - 1)
            to[u][c] = make_node(n - 1, inf)
            to[u][t] = v
            fpos[v] += pos - 1
            slen[v] -= pos - 1
            to[node][edge] = u
            link[last] = u
            last = u
        if(node == 0):
            pos -= 1
        else:
            node = link[node]

def init_tree(st):
    global slen, ans, inf, maxn, s, to, fpos, slen, link, node, pos, sz, n

    inf = int(1e9)
    maxn = len(st)*2+1 #int(1e6+1)
    s = [0]*maxn
    to = [{} for i in range(maxn)]
    fpos, slen, link = [0]*maxn, [0]*maxn, [0]*maxn

    node, pos = 0, 0
    sz = 1
    n = 0

    slen[0] = inf
    ans = 0
    for c in st:
        add_letter(ord(c))


text = "TTTTTTTTTT" + 1777*"A" + "$"
query = 1750*"A"

def traverse_edge(st, idx, start, end):
    global len_text, len_st
    k = start
    while k <= end and k < len_text and idx < len_st:
        if text[k] != st[idx]:
            return -1
        k += 1
        idx += 1
    if idx == len_st:
        return idx
    return 0

def edgelen(v, init, e):
    if(v == 0):
        return 0
    return e-init+1

def dfs(node, leafs, off):
    if not node:
        return
    k, tree = node
    if not isinstance(tree, int): # it is a node pointing to other nodes
        for kk, value in tree.items():
            if slen[value] > 190000000:
                leafs.append(fpos[value]-off)
            else:
                dfs((kk, to[value]), leafs, off+slen[value])

def traverse(v, st, idx, depth=0):
    global len_st
    result = cache.get((v, st), -2)
    if result != -2:
        return result
    r = -1
    init = fpos[v]
    end = fpos[v]+slen[v]
    e = end-1
    if v != 0:
        r = traverse_edge(st, idx, init, e)
        if r != 0:
            if r == -1:
                cache[(v, st)] = []
                return []
            depth += r
            # Here is when we found a match
            leafs = []
            dfs((v, to[v]), leafs, depth)
            #return reversed(leafs)
            return leafs
    idx = idx + edgelen(v, init, e)
    if idx > len_st:
        cache[(v, st)] = []
        return []
    k = ord(st[idx])
    children = to[v]
    if k in children:
        vv = children.get(k, 0)
        matches = traverse(vv, st, idx, depth)
        cache[(v, st)] = matches
        return matches
    return []


def main():
    global text, len_st, len_text, cache
    init_tree(text)
    len_text = len(text)
    len_st = len(query)
    r = []
    #cache = {}
    for runs in range(1000):
        cache = {}
        matches = traverse(0, query, 0)
        r.append("\n".join(str(m) for m in matches))
    stdout.write("\n".join(r)+"\n")

main()
```

Answer (score 5):

So, about all those `global`s. They make your code *really* hard to read, I have almost no idea what is going on (after having read it twice). The general recommendation is to only use `global` objects if you really have to. Otherwise pass the objects either as arguments to the function, or write a class which has the relevant variables as attributes and keep the state like this.

Another thing that makes your code a lot easier to understand (both for other people and for yourself in two months time), are [`docstring`s](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), which document what each function does, the parameters it takes and what it returns or modifies.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was just porting this code http://ideone.com/sT8Vd1, explained in https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/16780. In the original code they were using global variables (which is very common in competitive programming implementations) so I tried to keep it the closer I could so it could be easier to compare in my tests. I appreciate your advise about docstrings to make the code clear also

Answer (score -2):

I finally gave up trying to optimize Pypy and wrote the code I needed just in C++. Here is it in case somebody is curious:

````
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

#define fpos adla
const int inf = 1e9;
const int maxn = 1e6+1;
//#define maxn 100005

char s[maxn];
map<int,int> to[maxn];
int slen[maxn], fpos[maxn], link[maxn];
int node, pos;
int sz = 1, n = 0;

int text_len;
char text[maxn];
int query_len;
char query[maxn];

int make_node(int _pos, int _len) {
    fpos[sz] = _pos;
    slen[sz] = _len;
    return sz++;
}

void go_edge() {
    while(pos > slen[to[node][s[n - pos]]]) {
        node = to[node][s[n - pos]];
        pos -= slen[node];
    }
}

void add_letter(int c) {
    s[n++] = c;
    pos++;
    int last = 0;
    while(pos > 0) {
        go_edge();
        int edge = s[n - pos];
        //int &v = to[node][edge];
        int v = to[node][edge];
        int t = s[fpos[v] + pos - 1];
        if(v == 0) {
            //v = make_node(n - pos, inf);
            to[node][edge] = make_node(n - pos, inf);
            link[last] = node;
            last = 0;
        }
        else if(t == c) {
            link[last] = node;
            return;
        }
        else {
            int u = make_node(fpos[v], pos - 1);
            to[u][c] = make_node(n - 1, inf);
            to[u][t] = v;
            fpos[v] += pos - 1;
            slen [v] -= pos - 1;
            // v = u;
            to[node][edge] = u;
            link[last] = u;
            last = u;
        }
        if(node == 0)
            pos--;
        else
            node = link[node];
    }
}

int traverse_edge(char st[], int st_len, int idx, int start, int end) {
    int k = start;
    while (k <= end && k < text_len && idx < st_len) {
        if (text[k] != st[idx]) {
            return -1;
        }
        k += 1;
        idx += 1;
    }
    if (idx == st_len) {
        return idx;
    }
    return 0;
}

int edgelen(int v, int init, int e) {
    if (v == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return e-init+1;
}

void dfs(map<int, int> tree, vector<vector<int>> leafs, int off) {
    if (tree.empty()) {
        return;
    }
        /* for ( auto [k, value] : tree) { */ // C++17
        for ( auto it : tree) {
            int value = it.second;
            if (slen[value] > maxn / 10) {
                vector<int> leaf;
                leaf.push_back(fpos[value]);
                leaf.push_back(slen[value]);
                leaf.push_back(fpos[value]-off);
                leafs.push_back(leaf);
            } else {
                dfs(to[value], leafs, off+slen[value]);
            }
        }
}

pair<bool, vector<int>> traverse(int v, map<int,int> tree, char st[], int idx, int depth) {
    int r = -1;
    int init = fpos[v];
    int end = fpos[v]+slen[v];
    int e = end - 1;
    if (v != 0) {
        r = traverse_edge(st, query_len, idx, init, e);
        if (r != 0) {
            if (r == -1) {
                return {false, vector<int>{}}; 
            }
            vector<int> matches;
            return {true, matches};
        }
    }
    idx = idx + edgelen(v, init, e);
    if (idx > query_len) {
        return {false, vector<int>{}}; 
    }
    int k = int(st[idx]);
    map<int,int> children = to[v];
    /* if (children.contains(k)) { */ // C++20 
    if (children.find(k) != children.end()) {
        int vv = tree[k];
        return traverse(vv, to[vv], st, idx, depth);
    }
    return pair<bool, vector<int>>(false, vector<int>{});
}


int main() {
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
        while (t--) {
            scanf("%s", text);
            text_len = strlen(text);

            for (int i=0; i<maxn; i++) {
                to[i] = map<int,int>{};
            }
            sz = 1;
            n = 0;
            pos = 0;
            node = 0;
            slen[0] = inf;

            for (int i=0; i<text_len; i++) {
                add_letter((int)text[i]);
            }
            add_letter((int)'$');

            int q;
            scanf("%d", &q);
                while (q--) {
                    scanf("%s", query);
                    query_len = strlen(query);
                    pair<bool, vector<int>> results = traverse(0, to[0], query, 0, 0);
                    printf("%s\n", results.first ? "y" : "n");
                }
        }
}
```
````